# Trouble Building Python OpenCV with Cuda on Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, opencv

I'm trying to build OpenCV 3.4.15 with `Cuda` support for Python 3.9.5 on Windows 10 and am getting stuck. I've followed a number of tutorials and I think I'm close, but I seem to be missing something.

I've run `CMake` with WITH_CUDA enabled, and everything seems to be working great. I open OpenCV.sln and build ALL_BUILD and and then build INSTALL. Everything builds successfully, and the `Cuda` support on the C++ side works great. On the Python side, I end up with files added to the following path, and non-`Cuda` OpenCV in Python seems to work fine.

```
C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\cv2
```

If I run `cv2.getBuildInformation()` I see the following, which makes me think I was successful (this didn't show up with the pip install version of OpenCV).

```
NVIDIA CUDA:                   YES (ver 11.4, CUFFT CUBLAS)
  NVIDIA GPU arch:             35 37 50 52 60 61 70 75 80 86
  NVIDIA PTX archs:
```

However, if I run `cv2.cuda.getCudaEnabledDeviceCount()` I get the following.

```
AttributeError: module 'cv2.cuda' has no attribute 'getCudaEnabledDeviceCount'
```

When I run the same command with OpenCV installed through `pip`, this successfully outputs 0.

One thing I noticed is that the `site-packages/cv2` directory I created from source is only about 6MB, while `the site-packages/cv2` directory I get from `pip` install is nearly 100MB, so something seems off.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that building OpenCV 4.5.4 instead of OpenCV 3.4.15 resolved the issue.  The Python bindings to the OpenCV Cuda implementations are now available.

Comment: Can you provide more information, what solved the issue. Where can you course this version. Etc